# Xamarin.Android / MvvmCross : Navigation with MvxSpinner

Tags: xamarin, navigation, viewmodel, mvvmcross

I have an issue with an Mvvmcross / Xamarin application in droid part.
I have made a "MvxSpinner menu" wich is bind on a list of couple 
ViewModel.cs

```
private List<CoupleIntString> _actions = new List<CoupleIntString>() {
    new CoupleIntString(0,"Actions"),
    new CoupleIntString(1,  "Mail"),
    new CoupleIntString(2,"Imprimer"),
    new CoupleIntString(3, "Totaux"),
    new CoupleIntString(4, "Fiche client")
};

public List<CoupleIntString> Actions {
    get { return _actions; }
    set {
        _actions = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Actions);
    }
}
```

droid.axml

```
<MvxSpinner
    android:id="@+id/action_spinner"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_spinner"
    local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/item_spinnerdropdown"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Actions;SelectedItem ActionSelected" />
```

When I select one item, I set the SelectedAction of my FirstViewModel and show the viewmodel I want to load.

```
public CoupleIntString ActionSelected {
    set {
        int xx = value.intPart;
        switch (xx) {
        case 1: //mail
            GoToMailCommand.Execute();
            break;
        case 2: //impression
            GoToImpressionCommand.Execute();
            break;
        case 3: //totaux
            GoToTotauxCommand.Execute();
            break;
        case 4: //impression
            GoToDetailsClientCommand.Execute();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

But, when i come back on the FirstViewModel, it automatically  re-set the SelectedAction and go back to the second Viewmodel.
I have tried to set my SelectedAction to none in Init, ReloadState, Start, InitFromBundle and  ReloadFromBundle but after all these calls, there is another one with the value I selected before and I don't know where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to add a SelectedItem listener and set SelectedItem to 0.

```
var spinner = FindViewById<MvxSpinner>(Resource.Id.action_spinner);
spinner.ItemSelected += Spinner_ItemSelected;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this doesn't work. And also,  we are trying to have as less code as possible in the droid part.

Answer (score 0):

MvvmCross has a `SelectedItem` target binding for `MvxSpinner`, you are almost right with your code. However, you need to use a command instead of a property for the `SelectedItem` binding to work:

```
private MvxCommand<CoupleIntString> _itemSelected;
public ICommand ItemSelected =>
    _itemSelected = _itemSelected ?? 
        (_itemSelected = new MvxCommand<CoupleIntString>(DoItemSelected));

private void DoItemSelected(CoupleIntString item)
{
    ActionSelected = item;
}
```

Then make your binding look like:

```
local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Actions; SelectedItem ItemSelected"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't work, when I select one Item I get this warning : 
 MvxBind:Warning: 62,44 SetValue ignored in binding - target property is readonly
and nothing else happens.

(I've edited your code  :  i changed ICommand _itemSelected to MvxCommand<CoupleIntString> _itemSelected)